# Why does Xcode Fail to complete App Upload

Tags: xcode, app-store, watchos

I have a new "independent" watchOS 8 app built with Xcode 13.1 that I wish to put in the App Store.
I have current profiles, distribution certificates etc.

I archive it and try to push the archive via Xcode Organizer/Distribute. It passes all the tests and uploads roughly the correct about of data (size of .ipa) to a blobstore.apple.com URL.
Then it just stops, for up to hours before I kill the process. No messages or Alerts.

Is there a log file somewhere which monitors the app upload process so I can try to diagnose the issue? I ran through a number on logs in Console but did not see anything related.  Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

A kindly Framework Engineer replied:

There should be a log at
~/Library/Application Support/com.apple.dt.Xcode.ITunesSoftwareService/Logs that might be illuminating.

Comment: Unfortunately these logs seem to be only saved when a upload operation succeeds. I have 5 log files and they show completion times of about 7 minutes. But I frequently get "operation time out" when uploading, after waiting for 30 minutes or longer, and there are no logs to show why.